# Debugging non working Pascal Check condition (DirExists) in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I trying to compile a little setup program for future users, I have understood how change some stuff.

But now I would like to create a shortcut ONLY if the directory exist. I tried to do something like that but nothing happened ... :

```
[Icons]
; Start menu icon
Name: "{group}\Myprogram"; Filename: "{app}\Myprogram.exe"
; Desktop icon
Name: "{userdesktop}\Myprogram.exe"; Filename: "{app}\Myprogram.exe"; \
 Check: DirExists(ExpandConstant('C:\[path]\test'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok. It should do what you want. To help with the debugging, implement a user function that logs the test like:

```pascal
[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\P680.exe"; Filename: "{app}\P680.exe"; \
  Check: DirExistsLogged('C:\Users\administrator\Documents\Test')

[Code]

function DirExistsLogged(Path: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := DirExists(Path);
  Log(Format('DirExists [%s] => %d', [Path, Result]));
end;
```

---

Log example, when the folder exists:

```
2019-12-31 15:04:59.565   DirExists [C:\Users\administrator\Documents\Test] => 1
2019-12-31 15:04:59.565   -- Icon entry --
2019-12-31 15:04:59.565   Dest filename: C:\Users\martin\Desktop\My Program.exe.lnk
2019-12-31 15:04:59.566   Creating the icon.
2019-12-31 15:04:59.583   Successfully created the icon.
2019-12-31 15:04:59.594   Saving uninstall information.
```

---

Log example, when the folder does not exist:

```
2019-12-31 15:06:23.960   DirExists [C:\Users\administrator\Documents\Test] => 0
2019-12-31 15:06:23.960   Saving uninstall information.
```

Comment: I just understood by reading my first post again. Yes indeed if the directory exists the shortcut will be created, but I would like it to be created in the directory that it has just checked.
For example if the path 'C:\Users\administrator\Documents\Test'  exists then the shortcut is created in this path 'C:\Users\administrator\Documents\Test'
Sorry, I did not take a step back, from my point of view it seemed obvious

Comment: So put the path to the `Filename` parameter.